# Why $m^*(Q)=|Q|$ if $Q$ is a cube.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Q$ a closed cube of $\mathbb R^d$ and we denote $|Q|$ his volume. I want to prove that $m^*(Q)=|Q|$ where $$m^*(E)=\inf\sum_{k=1}^\infty |Q_j|$$
where $E\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Q_j$ and $Q_j$ are closed cube.

**Proof**

Since $Q$ cover itself, $m^*(Q)\leq |Q|$. Let proof the reverse inequality. Let the covering $$Q\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Q_j$$
where $Q_j$ are closed cube. It suffice to prove that $|Q|\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j|$.

(By the way, isn't it obvious that $|Q|\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j|$ ?)

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $S_j$ an open cube that contain $Q_j$ and such that $$|S_j|\leq (1+\varepsilon)|Q_j|.$$

For the rest of the proof it's fine. I just don't understand why there exist such a $S_j$. Moreover, wouldn't it be $S_j$ an open cube that contain $Q_j$ and such that $|S_j|\leq |Q_j|+\varepsilon$ ? But still, why such a $S_j$ exist ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342703/help-with-a-proof-regarding-outer-measure) .

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on MSE !

Let $Q_j=[a_j,b_j]^d$. Then, for all $\varepsilon>0$, 
$$]a_j-\varepsilon,b_j+\varepsilon[^d \supset [a_j,b_j]^d=Q_j.$$

Set $S_j=]a_j-\varepsilon,b_j+\varepsilon[^d$ to get the result. Notice that the existence of cube $S_j$ such that $|S_j|\leq |Q_j|+\varepsilon$ is not true in general. However, the existence of an open $S_j\supset Q_j$ such that $|S_j|\leq |Q_j|+\varepsilon$ is true (where $|S_j|$ mean the volume of $S_j$) and is a consequence of the fact that a closed set is measurable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't really understand why there is no cube $S_j$ that contain $Q_j$ and such that $|S_j|\leq |Q_j|+\varepsilon$. And if $Q_j$ was not a cube but a rectangle or an other closed and bounded set, would we have a cube $S_j$ such that $|S_j|\leq (1+\varepsilon)|Q_j|$ ?

Comment: I didn't say that there exist a $S_j$ such that $|S_j|\leq |Q_j|+\varepsilon$ is wrong, I said that it's wrong in general (but here it's true since $S_j$ and $Q_j$ are both cubes). For your last question, the answer is no because we don't have an homothetic transformation between a cube and a rectangle which is not a cube.

Comment: Ok I see, and if $Q_j$ is not of the form $[a,b]^d$ but of the form $ABCD$ where $A=(1,0), B=(0,1),C=(-1,0)$ and $D=(0,-1)$ ? (I took a concret example in $\mathbb R^2$, which is not of the form $[a,b]^2$, I hope you'll understand).

Comment: It doesn't matter since there is a rotation (which is bijective) $R$ such that $R(Q_j)=[a,b]^d$. And thus if $S_j$ is a square such that $|S_j|\leq |R(Q_j)|+\varepsilon$, then $R^{-1}(S_j)$ is a square s.t. $|R^{-1}(S_j)|\leq |Q_j|+\varepsilon$.